# java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String Unable to start activity Component Info

Tags: java, android

I got the error 
       my code snippet is here.

```
 switch (message.what) {
                case 1:

                Bundle bundle = message.getData();
                latitude = bundle.getString("latitude");
                longitude = bundle.getString("longitude")
               break;
            default:
                locationAddress = null;
        }
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), latitude + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sh.edit();
        editor.putString(SharedPrefManager.RESTAURANT_LAT, String.valueOf(latitude));
        editor.putString(SharedPrefManager.RESTAURANT_LON, String.valueOf(longitude));
        Log.d("ResultRestroSave", String.valueOf(editor));

        Log.d("ResultRestrodata", latitude + longitude);


    }
```

Another my code snippet is here

I got the error

java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String

```
 sh = DriverMapsActivity.this.getSharedPreferences(SharedPrefManager.SHARED_PREF_NAME,MODE_PRIVATE);
     // Error in this line


 res_latitude = Double.parseDouble(sh.getString(SharedPrefManager.RESTAURANT_LAT,""));
            res_longitude = Double.parseDouble(sh.getString(SharedPrefManager.RESTAURANT_LON,""));
```

Comment: you are getting error because your string is empty check your longitude and latitude values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things missing with your approach:

**- missing commit after `editor.putString(SharedPrefManager.RESTAURANT_LON, String.valueOf(longitude));`**

```
    ...
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sh.edit();
    editor.putString(SharedPrefManager.RESTAURANT_LAT, String.valueOf(latitude));
    editor.putString(SharedPrefManager.RESTAURANT_LON, String.valueOf(longitude));
    Log.d("ResultRestroSave", String.valueOf(editor));

    Log.d("ResultRestrodata", latitude + longitude);
    editor.commit();

    ...
```

**- Instead of `sh.getString(SharedPrefManager.RESTAURANT_LAT,"");` use**

```
          res_latitude = Double.parseDouble(sh.getString(SharedPrefManager.RESTAURANT_LAT,"0"));
          res_longitude = Double.parseDouble(sh.getString(SharedPrefManager.RESTAURANT_LON,"0"));
```

Comment: @Arish great! remember to approve answer if it was useful, so that others can benefit too